# URL matching non iteratively

Tags: java, tomcat, pattern-matching, uri

I have list of http paths and methods. Ex:

```
GET /spaceshuttles/{id}
POST /{version}/order
```

From what I understand, when there's an incoming request, these paths are compared iteratively, stopping at the first match.
My question is - does that have a performance hit? What if there's a service handling 1000's of incoming routes, how much would be the hit in performance?

Even if the hit is small, is there a clean strategy to match URL's with a tree/trie-like matching strategy? If yes, then what?
For example:
I want to match an incoming URL to one of these without iterating for a match.
Ex: For **GET /spaceshuttles/46** I should get a handle to **GET /spaceshuttles/{id}**

I need this for my web app filter where some URLs get a special treatment.
Currently I am doing a match by iterating against my list. I am assuming there must already be some library that does this in an efficient trie way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a library in mind that would fit your needs. I would go for a custom class `RequestMatcher` holding a regexp pattern and a Http method or String with the Http method:

```
class RequestMatcher {
    private Pattern urlPattern;
    private String httpMethod;

   public RequestMatcher(final String urlPattern, final String httpMethod) {
        this.urlPattern = Pattern.compile(urlPattern);
        this.httpMethod = httpMethod;
    }

    public boolean matches(final String url, final String httpMethod) {
        return httpMethod.equals(this.httpMethod) && this.urlPattern.matcher(url).matches();
    }
```

In your filter you could then use it like this:

```
final RequestMatcher spaceShuttleMatcher = new RequestMatcher("/spaceshuttles/[0-9]+", "GET");
final RequestMatcher orderMatcher = new RequestMatcher("/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+/order", "POST");
boolean isSpaceShuttleRequest = spaceShuttleMatcher.matches("/spaceshuttles/123", "GET");
boolean isOrderMatcher = orderMatcher.matches("/1.2.3/order", "POST");
```